# How to export state variable from one component to another component in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

```
//SignIn.js
function SignIn() {
   const [username, setUsername] = useState('Mickey')
   if (//condition if true):
      setUsername('Mickey Mouse');
   return(
      <div><h1>{username}</h1></div>
   )
}
export default SignIn;

//Target.js
function Target() {
    return(
      <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
   )
}
```

Just for example suppose I have two components SignIn.js and Target.js (with all necessary imports). I want to pass/export/transfer username state variable from SignIn.js to Target.js. How do I do that?

Comment: You don't. Pass it down as a prop (or if they're siblings, lift it up to a shared parent).

Answer (score 0):

To pass the `username` state variable from `SignIn.j`s to `Target.js` in React, you can use props. Here's an example

In `SignIn.js`, you'll need to import `Target` and pass the `username` as a prop:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Target from './Target';

function SignIn() {
   const [username, setUsername] = useState('Mickey');

   if (//condition if true) {
      setUsername('Mickey Mouse');
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <h1>{username}</h1>
         <Target username={username} />
      </div>
   )
}

export default SignIn;
```

In `Target.js`, you can receive the `username` prop like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function Target(props) {
   const { username } = props;

   return (
      <div>
         <h1>Hello, {username}</h1>
      </div>
   )
}

export default Target;
```

Now, when you render the `SignIn` component, it will also render the `Target` component and pass the `username` state variable as a prop. In `Target.js`, you can access `username` using `props.username`.

This way, the `Target` component will display "Hello, Mickey Mouse" if the condition in `SignIn.js` is true.

Comment: return (
      <div>
         <h1>{username}</h1>
         <Target username={username} />
      </div>
   )                                 Here if I call Target component in return of SignIn.js component then Target.js component's return will be displayed below SignIn.js component's return ui

Comment: Actually what I want to do is, I have two components, one for navbar n one for signin page......I want to pass/export signed in user's username to navbar component so that I can replace the signin button with signed in user's username